# I am not a dragon. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, video-games

> I have wings, but you have to teach me *fly*.
>
> I spew fire, but I am not a *dragon*.
>
> I am the older of three *brothers*.

**Who am I?**

**HINT:**

> Words in italics are not exactly what they mean. Think about them!

Comment: Way too niche ...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have an answer that fits, but relies on knowledge of a specific franchise.

> You are the Pokemon Charizard.

I have wings, but you have to teach me fly.

> Charizard has wings, but does not learn the move Fly naturally. It must be taught to it via HM.

I spew fire, but I am not a dragon.

> When animated, Charizard uses its fire moves by breathing fire. Although it looks like a dragon, it does not have the Dragon type. It is Flying and Fire instead.

I am the older of three brothers.

> It is the third-stage evolution of Charmander and Charmeleon.

Comment: I wouldn't answer better :)

Comment: I knew this the second I saw it as well. XD

Comment: Huh: apparently Charizard can learn *Fly* since Yellow. This was my first thought, but I dismissed it because I thought that I knew that Charizard couldn't learn *Fly*. TIL.

Comment: that  is quite an insider riddle!..

Answer (score 19):

I know the answer has already been accepted, but when I read this I got a very different answer.

You are

> The Nuclear Bomb

I have wings, but you have to teach me fly.

> Nukes have wings on their tails to stabilize their flight. Mechanical devices do not know how to fly, unless there is some sort of guidance system.

I spew fire, but I am not a dragon.

> Obviously not a dragon, and a very historical record of its fire

I am the older of three brothers.

> This line is the biggest reason I like my answer. August 9th 1945 Oppenheimer's Atomic bomb drops in Japan. October 30 1961, the soviet union tested the bigger brother of the Atom bomb, the Tsar bomba, the biggest bomb ever detonated on earth. Which leads to our current Nuclear bomb- the biggest and baddest brother.

Comment: That's quite a nice and original answer, but I see a little mistake in your deduction, as in terms of time, the current Nuclear Bomb is the *youngest* but not the oldest brother. But still close enough to get a +1. @JasonV

Comment: yeah, i realized once i was typing it out about the "oldest" but i felt that it followed the pattern of the intended answer. If you really think about it, charizard evolves from charmeleon, who evolves from charmander. Technically, charmander is the "oldest" but the intent is there, and it's the example i followed.

Comment: Following the example is true that you are right, but I was thinking about the *level* as if it was the *age*, so that Charizard is *older* that way. But anyway, I take it, I really like your answer. @JasonV

Comment: @D.Mellow Something like "I am the biggest of three brothers" might improve the riddle -- age has nothing to do with a pokemon's evolution stage

Comment: @Pyritie well as I said before, I relate *age* with *level* so as you have to reach a high level to evolve, Charizard is the oldest of three "brothers/evolution stages*.

Comment: I think of evolving a pokemon more like moving from one level of education to the next. It's not like you just lost one student as another appeared, it's the same student transitioning. If you look at it this way, Charizard would always be older than *himself* when he was a Charmander...

Comment: if we are talking levels, my answer is even better! nuke level > a-bomb level

Comment: Just a date correction. The A-bomb was first used on Aug **06**, on Hiroshima. Then it was used on Aug **09** on Nagasaki. For comparison, the Trinity Test was Jly 16.